# How does the bip32 version bytes convert to base58?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, python, base58, base58check

Converting the BIP32 version bytes - `x04\x88\xad\xe4` - from base256 to base58 and base58Check returns `7irrX` and `1kz713TZjju`, respectively.

I thought the version bytes represented `xprv`. What am I missing?

I'm using *pybitcointools*, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Why from base256? 0x04 0x88 0xAD 0xE4 should directly go into base58 IMO.

Comment: @JonasSchnelli only because the pybitcointools library defines it that way. It makes no difference if it's encoded as hex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like in regular bitcoin addresses (or anything base 58 encoded), the version bytes don't get encoded by themselves. As described in the [Serialization format](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#serialization-format) section, there is 78 byte payload that gets versioned and checksumed before then being encoded into base 58:

> - 4 byte: version bytes (mainnet: 0x0488B21E public, 0x0488ADE4 private; testnet: 0x043587CF public, 0x04358394 private)
> - 1 byte: depth: 0x00 for master nodes, 0x01 for level-1 derived keys, ....
> - 4 bytes: the fingerprint of the parent's key (0x00000000 if master key)
> - 4 bytes: child number. This is ser32(i) for i in xi = xpar/i, with xi the key > - being serialized. (0x00000000 if master key)
> - 32 bytes: the chain code
> - 33 bytes: the public key or private key data (serP(K) for public keys, 0x00 || ser256(k) for private keys)

There's not a byte-to-character mapping when you do base58 serialization of a multi-byte structure. It's not like 0x04 becomes 'x', 0x88 becomes 'p', etc. Rather, the whole 86 (78 payload + 4 version + 4 checksum) byte structure gets encoded to something that starts with 'xpriv' when the 4 most significant bytes of the 86 bytes structure are [0x04, 0x88, 0xad, 0xe4].

Comment: So it only works for 78 byte structures? If so, I understand

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie it's likely that a different sequence of 4 bytes could get a 50 byte structure to start with xpriv, for example, but yes, those exact bytes were chosen for a 78 byte structure.

Comment: I tried and tried again and it wouldn't work. Then I realised it's not 78, it's actually **82 bytes** when you include the 4 byte checksum. In pybitcointools; `changebase(TESTNET_PRIVATE + bytes(bytearray(78)), 256, 58) >>> 'tprv8ZgxMBicQKsPcsbCVeqqF1KVdH7gwDJbxbzpCxDUsoXHdb6SnTPYxdwSAKDC6KKJzv7khnNWRAJQsRA8BBQyiSfYnRt6zuu4vZQGKhCz4Jb`. :)

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie, good point! I've updated my answer.

Comment: For future reference: all bitcoin extended key version bytes can be found at https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xpub_version_bytes.html

Answer (score 1):

To complement the answer above, the Bitcoin [chainparams.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp) file contains the following information to assist in achieving BIP 32 compliance:

Mainnet:

```
base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = boost::assign::list_of(0x04)(0x88)(0xB2)(0x1E).convert_to_container<std::vector<unsigned char> >();
base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = boost::assign::list_of(0x04)(0x88)(0xAD)(0xE4).convert_to_container<std::vector<unsigned char> >();
```

Testnet:

```
base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = boost::assign::list_of(0x04)(0x35)(0x87)(0xCF).convert_to_container<std::vector<unsigned char> >();
base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = boost::assign::list_of(0x04)(0x35)(0x83)(0x94).convert_to_container<std::vector<unsigned char> >();
```

The bitcoin-explorer (bx) command is used below, with the 3rd worst possible brain wallet seed in the world. Additionally, bx was compiled for using testnet not mainnet. Hence, focus on where **04358394** for **tprv** and **043587cf** for **tpub** that appears in the examples below.

% echo '0' | bx base16-encode | bx sha512 | bx hd-new 
`tprv8ZgxMBicQKsPdcvudXaExR6Wdz5VgdjGeZHsw5bjnypoxrCxnYsyVq2v9cPTzDsnyLAL1v4Z2tM3Rp2AA6vv9WDbNBtui5QEZTWYucefZox`

% echo '0' | bx base16-encode | bx sha512 | bx hd-new | bx base58check-decode

```
wrapper
{
    checksum 3287061687
    payload 3583940000000000000000004b0dc73821a026c0c71d07a7655968352b52d7e5896dd3907df121f914f9743900a6b53d2f0e384dc6ced2caeb36f0c9cc6f3ab0677f73c31aca87b62bbcc9fe78
    version 4
}
```

% echo '0' | bx base16-encode | bx sha512 | bx hd-new | bx base58-decode
`04358394`0000000000000000004b0dc73821a026c0c71d07a7655968352b52d7e5896dd3907df121f914f9743900a6b53d2f0e384dc6ced2caeb36f0c9cc6f3ab0677f73c31aca87b62bbcc9fe78`b794ecc3`

% echo '0' | bx base16-encode | bx sha512 | bx hd-new | bx hd-public
`tpubD9nYDjxx7QwpsEhUiS7MDJ68p25nu9yxEt1AofKmEjmL3kozwA3z8G4Cm556YCYYJwfnix2GLVTtCHZq79R8UsRZBJVRPtD9HKNQBzDZVo4`

% echo '0' | bx base16-encode | bx sha512 | bx hd-new | bx hd-public | bx base58-decode
`043587cf`01cf633b1c00000000c023d310564ead16b50e678b2ff20e2d0a0f210fcf9c603ebd16f17d0510663802605d719a28b2707dcc9d7a2b804ba70242330e7010161aec4f86a0771d9909e504b705bf